# "Cretin" and "imbecile" in US English

Tags: word-usage, pejorative-language

How common is the insult "cretin" in US English? What minimum age and level of education do users of the word typically have?

Would you say that "cretin" is much less common than "imbecile" in US English? Which one is more offensive?

Comment: They're both learned words, and they're both insults, and they're both rare. If you wanna see which one's more common in insults in the US, feel free to collect data; there are no statistics available for speech.

Comment: I would say that "cretin" was a little more common than "imbecile", though both are quite rare in most environments.  The last instance of the word "cretin" I clearly recall hearing was out of the mouth of Major Winchester in the TV series MASH, and that was decades ago.

Comment: Hot Licks, thanks for your response. And which one does seem more dated nowadays?

Comment: Americans probably don't say "cretin" as often as I *think* they do. I wince every time I hear it pronounced the same as ***Cretan*** (to me, an inhabitant of Crete, with no implications as to mental capacity or absence thereof). It turns up with both pronunciations in Family Guy, but I don't know if they're deliberately poking fun at the "wrong" usage.

Comment: But be sure to listen to how people pronounce _cretin_. I've heard /'krɛtɪn/ -- clearly a spelling pronunciation -- instead of /'kritən/. And the fact that the correct English pronunciation of _cretin_ is indistinguishable from the correct English pronunciation of _Cretan_ gives the Paradox of the Liar a certain extra jouissance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: We seldom use *cretin* and use *imbecile* only a little more, but we don't stint on *moron* and *idiot*.

Comment: OED says **/ˈkrɛtɪn/**, formerly **/ˈkriːtɪn/**, which seems odd to me given it's from French **crétin**. For me, the current *mot du jour* is **woodentop**. Stewie in Family Guy is fond of **moron**, but I'd say Brian (the dog) favours **idiot**.

Comment: Yeah, "moron" and "idiot" are still in fairly wide use in the US, likely "idiot" more than "moron".  "Moron" has a tiny bit of a non-PC flavor to it, but "idiot" is generally considered to be an "acceptable" insult -- not viewed as alluding to the mentally disabled (at least not very strongly).

Comment: I can't speak for Americans but my 9-year-old Mancunian grandson had never heard of either *cretin* or *imbecile*. When asked for a synonym of *idiot* he offered *mong*, which I needed to check with an urban dictionary for confirmation of meaning.

Comment: Neither is very common.  Imbecile is more common in the midwestern USA.  However, it has a connotation of being "an insult only used by pretentious people".  Cretin has the same connotation, but it's even less likely to be understood.  

More colloquial words having the same meaning would be:  moron, idiot, fool, dipstick, tool, twit, dimwit, stooge, jackass, loser, birdbrain, blockhead, clown, buffoon, halfwit, numskull, sucker, dunce, dope.  All of those would be understood by any American.  Cretin and imbecile are not as likely to be understood.

Comment: Like cretin and imbecile, moron and idiot were originally medical terms for those with intellectual deficiencies. Flying in the face of the PC movement is the (now considered derisive) "special".

Comment: Google Ngrams shows that use of _imbecile_ has dropped significantly since the 1920's, which is when _mentally retarded_ appears to have replaced it. _cretin_ peaked in the 1920's and 1940's, but has also dropped, although not as much.

Comment: Of course, [Cretin Derham Hall](https://www.cretin-derhamhall.org/) is a hoity-toity private high school in St Paul, Minnesota.  So not all Cretin's are created equally.  (And Google searches are apt to get lots of bogus hits on the school name, as they are frequently in sports news.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In written U.S. English since 1800, *cretin* has always been considerably less common than *imbecile*, as this Ngram chart for the years 1750 through 2008 shows (the blue line tracks the frequency of *cretin*; the red line, the frequency of *imbecile*):

[image]

According to *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), *imbecile* is a French import that entered English in 1802; in contemporaneous French, *imbécile* meant "weak" or "weak-minded." For its part, *cretin* arrived in English in 1779, from a French dialect word *crétin* meaning "wretch" or "innocent victim" and ultimately deriving from the Latin word *christianus* ("Christian").

In Google Books search results, *imbecile* takes off against *cretin* during the period from 1800 to 1850 (approximately). Popularization of *cretin* may have been limited by the adoption in 1801 of *cretinism* as the name for a specific medical condition:

> a usu. congenital abnormal condition marked by physical stunting and mental retardation and caused by severe hypothyroidism

according to the *Eleventh Collegiate*. Meanwhile, *imbecile* was free to develop as an all-purpose characterization/insult for "a person affected with moderate mental retardation" and so, figuratively, a fool or idiot.

In any event, a review of all matches for *cretin* from the Google Books database for the years 1750–1869 turns up more than 200 matches for *cretin* (sometimes as a surname), and the vast majority are in the context of scientific or quasi-scientific discussions of the physiological condition. There is not one instance during this 110-year period of the term used as an insult; and only rarely does it show up even as a layman's descriptive term.

*Imbecile*, on the other hand (and perhaps in part because it appears early on in its English incarnation as an adjective as well as a noun) very quickly acquires figurative use. For example, from [*The Political Register*](https://books.google.com/books?id=h58rAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA122-IA1&dq=%22imbecile%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dEgmVfDeHNe3oQSX3IDIBg&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAjhQ#v=onepage&q=%22imbecile%22&f=false), (September 1770):

> I must therefore own to you, Sir, that I have waited with impatience the arrival of every post since this dreadful event [a fire at the dock-yard in Portsmouth], in hopes I should hear that the authors of this mischief were discovered : but hitherto in vain ; and I now think there is little room to expect we shall receive any satisfaction on the subject. The terms of the admiralty advertisement are of a piece with all the other measures of our present **imbecile** administration.

From a [review of *Walks in Edinburgh*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QmEAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA341&dq=%22imbecile%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lUMmVc7iHJLgoATMgIH4CQ&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q=%22imbecile%22&f=false), in *The Edinburgh Magazine and Literary Magazine* (September 1825):

> Pray what authority has Mr Chambers for calling that ugly barn which contains the libraries of the Advocates, and Writers to the Signet, a beautiful modern building? or how can he speak with patience of the site of the County-Hall, over which the half-ruined Cathedral of St Giles sits grinning, in all its frightful ugliness, like an **imbecile**, bigotted priest, anxious to throttle every mortal within his ken who is not as **imbecile** and bigotted as himself?

And from Marchioness of Lemington, [*Rosina; Or, The Virtuous Country Maid*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AEDQAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA113&dq=%22imbecile%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OEgmVYb8D8HfoASw1IGAAw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBDgy#v=onepage&q=%22imbecile%22&f=false), fifth edition (1827):

> I recollected that my mother had frequently assured me that nunneries abounded with the most virtuous and devout ladies ; but then I had heard others assert with confidence that they were mostly very naughty women. This perplexed me a little. I then blamed myself for submitting so tamely to Lady Beckford's directions. "Why," said I to myself, "I am not such an **imbecile** as to be incapable of directing my own actions. Is it necessary, then, that I should be locked up? and in a foreign country, too? Was I not in a land of liberty? and could not the laws protect me? Why, then, should I fly so cowardly, and—"

The 1770 date for the first example using *imbecile* above is a bit startling, considering that the noun *imbecile* supposedly didn't reach English until 1802 (Merriam-Webster doesn't provide a date for the appearance of the adjective form). But even more starling is MW's assertion that the noun *imbecility* has been in English since circa 1533. I'm not sure what to make of the extreme split in origin dates reported for the two words.

In 19o8, [Henry Goddard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_H._Goddard) translated the Binet IQ test into English, and in 1910 he introduced three categories of descriptive labels (based on IQ scores) that soon made their way into common parlance as insults, if they weren't there already: *idiot* (for an IQ score of 0–25); *imbecile* (for a score of 26–50); and *moron* (for a score of 51–75). The classification system persisted until the early 1970s, [according to one account](http://www.campbellmgold.com/archive_esoteric/morons_imbeciles_idiots.pdf). Despite widespread online assertions to the contrary, it appears that the IQ labeling system never included *cretin* as a category name.

---

With regard to the question of whether *cretin* or *imbecile* is more offensive, I think that any answer you received would be extremely subjective. Because both terms emerged out of scientific efforts at naming and describing debilitating mental conditions and significantly below-average intellectual capacity, both have the potential to be taken as very grave insults. I wouldn't use either term as an epithet in everyday life under any circumstances.